# How to retrieve future versions of my code after rollback on Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, ios, json, mobile, parse-platform

I have been using Parse for my iPhone app. I have some cloud code on there that's used to retrieve flight info from a flightstats api.

I have a question regarding Parse rollback. I rolled back to a previous version of my cloud code on parse, but then when I rolled forward, I couldn't find the future versions of the cloud code.

When I type 'parse releases' in terminal, the only version I see are:

```
v173 
v174 
v175 
v192
```

What happened to versions 176 through 191? Did they disappear or get deleted?

Comment: Is there any user documentation about this feature?

Comment: There is not any user documentation regarding which versions of cloud code are stored on parse. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Rollback generally deletes your files and changes made to the text to the point where you rollback to.
 So it is not possible to restore to an point after your rollback operation. i.e., if you have restore to v174 it is not possible to go again to v175 or v192.

It is always advised to use GIT or svn like things and to make a commit or push before your deploy to parse.

Thank you